# How to check that shortcode is empty in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am using the WooCommerce plugin. I created a sale page and use `[sale_products]` shortcode of WooCommerce. It shows me all sales product perfectly, now I want that if there are no sale products, the message will be show "there is no sale product".

Like this:

```
if(!empty([sale_products])) {
    [sale_products]
} else {
    // message
}
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: That's a big no no. Shortcodes usage is meant for (usually) printing "modules" or "sections" in posts/pages without needing to program anything. Since you know PHP you shouldn't use shortcodes for conditions in your code, you should directly check the required values, using global variables or DB query or the plugin's functions.

Comment: I'll second @OfirBaruch , you should not use shortcodes in conditions, besides the condition will always return true so else part will never kick in. The easiest option out is to use a small jQuery snippet that will check if the container that displays sales products is empty, if it is then display a message.

Comment: thanx thanx alot bros ... now i got an idea to create my own shortcode for sale products and there i'll add condition ... thanx alot again

Answer (score 12):

```
$output = do_shortcode('[sale_products]');
if($output !== '') {
    echo $output;
}
```